# Selenium unable to find chromedriver in cygwin

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, cygwin

I have a simple setup with Selenium in Cygwin

```
[main] $ pip show selenium
Name: selenium
Version: 4.13.0
Summary:
Home-page: https://www.selenium.dev
Author:
Author-email:
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: certifi, trio, trio-websocket, urllib3
Required-by:
```

```
webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

However Selenium raises a FileNotFoundError when trying to locate chromedriver

```
    return webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
    self._start_process(self._path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 204, in _start_process
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1821, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\ben\\.cache\\selenium\\chromedriver\\win64\\117.0.5938.92\\chromedriver.exe'
```

It looks like the file already exists which seems to indicate that Selenium is downloading the driver correctly and the driver is found in the PATH

```
[main] $ ls 'C:\\Users\\ben\\.cache\\selenium\\chromedriver\\win64\\117.0.5938.92'
chromedriver.exe
```

I had a previous setup with webdriver_manager that worked fine, but am trying to switch over to using Selenium Manager.

Is this a python, Cygwin, or Selenium issue?